# Receiving_User is not working for Mass emails while using leads

Tags: mass-email

I am sending mass emails to leads using Receiving_User.Name related to record is "Campaign". But name is not showing. I am new to sales force.

I am using following line in "Text email template" not "html".

```
Dear {!Receiving_User.Name},
```

Any help will appreciated.

Comment: Please include a relevant excerpt of your email template and/or code that is sending these emails in your question by making an edit. You can format code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or clicking `{}`.

Comment: Since you want to send to Leads, you need to reference the Lead object, not Receiving_User.  See [Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=valid_merge_fields.htm&type=5) for general explanation of how email templates work.

Answer (score 2):

{!Receiving_User} and {!Sending_User} fields are used to target the actual user records. In communities, it targets the respective contact record. So it won't work in a case where lead records are the recipients.

You can check the list of user records by navigating to Setup | Manage Users | Mass Email Users

> Administrators and users with the “Manage Users” permission can use Receiving User merge fields for email templates to reference the recipient of the email.

Reference - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=merge_fields_email_templates_cex.htm&type=5

> On other note -  The following types of merge fields are not supported
>   in Lightning Experience email templates:
>
> - {!Receiving_User.field_name}
> - {!Sending_User.field_name}
> - {!BLANKVALUE(Contact.FirstName, "Valued Customer")}
> - {!Contact.FirstName, Valued Customer} Campaign merge fields (can’t be    used in list emails)

Comment: In short you are saying that this is not possible?